# Qt Console with Bash

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a program using the Qt framework.  I would like the user to be able to have access to a console/terminal from within the application itself.

In other words, the user should be greeted with a "BASH" prompt when they start the program.
I have looked into QTermWidget, but there doesn't seem to be too much documentation on it and it doesn't seem to be up to date either.

I've looked at QConsole, but it only seems to be able to run TCL/Python consoles.

How would I be able to embed a terminal into my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really not much tutorial needed for QTermWidget, [although there is one here](https://github.com/qterminal/qtermwidget/blob/master/src/main.cpp).

The purpose of the widget is that it does not require any complication. The code would be something like this without the extra settings:

```
QTermWidget *console = new QTermWidget();
QMainWindow *mainWindow = new QMainWindow();
mainWindow->setCentralWidget(console);
```

It is also not necessarily true that it is not up-to-date. It was recently updated to build against Qt 5 properly. If you lack anything, [please use the issue tracker on github](https://github.com/qterminal/qtermwidget/issues).

It should be more or less in mature and "complete" state, that is why you may not see heavy progress. It is just a widget after all, not a big framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could try QProcess. This is not strictly "embedding" a terminal in your app, but it it really easy to use, you can kick off a terminal that is owned by your app. You can even connect (with signals / slots) to its output and interact with it in a limited fashion... depends on what you need.

Here is the doc with some simple examples: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html

I am not at my Qt-PC today so I don't have an "interacting" example for you, but if you think this is a way for you to go then I can dig that out...

Comment: The OP seems to look for a full-fledged terminal, not process execution only.